# regex: find match only if inside start/stop section

Tags: c#, regex

I need tofind MATCH only if it is between START and STOP:

1. `blah START hello MATCH bye STOP blah`
2. `blah START hello MATCH STOP blah`
3. `blah MATCH blah START hello MATCH STOP blah`

e.g.: on line 3, only the 2nd MATCH should be found.

Please note that START, STOP and MATCH are not literals. They are expressed as parts regex of the regex.

Of course, a simplified but non elegant solution would consist in extracting the part between START and STOP and then looking for MATCH in there.

TIA,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@"START.*?(MATCH).*?STOP"
```

Just capture whatever "MATCH" is. You may have additional criteria for the things that can occur between START - MATCH - STOP (as opposed to just "."), if so, use a character class.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/\bSTART\b.*?\bMATCH\b.*?\bSTOP\b/
```

Of if you're trying to capture it and are not speaking of these actual words:

```
/START.*?(MATCH).*?STOP/
```